# Is it possible to register .mv domains?

Tags: domain-registration, top-level-domains

Some time ago I tried to register a tld from malvides and found out that it is only possible to register .com.mv or .net.mv but not .mv

Now I found [this website](http://www.marcaria.com/register/domain/domain_registration.asp?country=Maldives&curr=EUR&gclid=CPqmt5KgmKoCFZUS3wodRHRnzw) that offers registration of .mv.

I tried to search for some more information on registering this tld, but without success.

Does anyone know if this is really possible now?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is possible to register a .mv domain but you have to have a local presence in Maldives to do so.

Comment: Thanks John for the fast answer. The website offering this service states: _If your company does not meet the residence requirement, we will proceed with registration of the domain to the name of our representatives and make it available to you; this alternative would have no additional charge._ This sounds like they would register the domain for me. I never heard of this company. Don't know if they are reliable. Do you have any experience or background information?

Comment: I've heard of companies performing services like this. For example the state of Delaware is a very business friendly place to register your business. So what a lot of businesses do is register their business in Delaware using an address of another company that acts like the companies business presence there. So this seems plausible. For how much that company charges I would think they are legitimate but the only way to know for sure is to find someone who has used them. That may not be easy to do.

Comment: @Matt Handy I've never used them, but I would very, *very* carefully read the formal legal version(s) of all their ToS, registration, etc. information before proceeding with them, to find out exactly what the relationship will be. That summary sounds like, and probably is, them saying "we'll register the domain ourselves and let you use it." Which would mean *they* actually own it and could just as easily decide to stop letting you use it, whenever they want. Again: never used them, and that's not an accusation, but if I'm right it's a potential outcome and you'd probably have little recourse.